# Is there a way to repeat texture on Unity 3D object without specifying amount of tiles?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make two different objects with the same size of texture / **same material**, which should be repeating; Without making new material for every new object I create. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Material A on both objects should look the same, the cube on the right represents how it should look.

[image]

Comment: Depends on the shader you are using .. yours seems to use local space but you would need one that draws the texture in world space...(if you look closely also Material B is wrong since on the top the scale is different) Search for `Unity shader Worldspace texture` there are lot of results like e.g. [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mapping-texture-to-world-position-instead-of-object-position.94766/)

Comment: @derHugo thank you for setting me on the right track, I'm sure I will figure this out now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed and working!

I had to make a Unity shader, which uses world space instead of local space (default). This is the code of a shader I used:

```cs
Shader "Legacy Shaders/Diffuse - Worldspace" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Scale("Texture Scale", Float) = 1.0
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;
float _Scale;

struct Input {
    float3 worldNormal;
    float3 worldPos;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    float2 UV;
    fixed4 c;

    if (abs(IN.worldNormal.x) > 0.5) {
        UV = IN.worldPos.yz; // side
        c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALLSIDE texture
    }
    else if (abs(IN.worldNormal.z) > 0.5) {
        UV = IN.worldPos.xy; // front
        c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use WALL texture
    }
    else {
        UV = IN.worldPos.xz; // top
        c = tex2D(_MainTex, UV* _Scale); // use FLR texture
    }

    o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
}
ENDCG
}

Fallback "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit"
}
```

Fixed version:

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhbW.png)

Sources of Knowledge I used:

[Video tutorial by PushyPixels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s79Zu0F8fuY)

[Blocks of code taken from this blog](https://www.blog.radiator.debacle.us/2012/01/joys-of-using-world-space-procedural.html)

@derHugo set me on the right track, thank you!!